# How to collect gold coin only once in a level

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have some levels in my game. Some of the levels contain a gold coin. I need the player to be able to collect it only once. If the user plays the same level again the coin should not appear again. (I'm using unity and c#)

Here the Script attached to the coin:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Goldcoin : MonoBehaviour
{
    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.CompareTag("Player"))
         {
           SaveManager.Instance.state.goldcoin++;
           SaveManager.Instance.Save();
           Destroy(gameObject);
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Aniket, welcome to StackOverflow. Please include the code you have already worked on so that we can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is data persistance between scenes.

[Data persistence](https://learn.unity.com/tutorial/persistence-saving-and-loading-data) means that even if you close the app, or change the scene, this data will persist, won't be deleted.

If you want persistance only in the same program execution, you can have an object that won't be destroyed on every Scene load, using [DontDestroyOnLoad](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.DontDestroyOnLoad.html).

But if you want to keep this information between multiple executions of the app you need something else, like a file.
You can store the state of the current scene (or even the whole game) in a multiple ways, the easyiest one is:

1. Create a [Serializable](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Serializable.html) class that will keep the information of the scene/level.
2. Serialize that class into a file (like a [JSON](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/JSONSerialization.html)) when you want to save changes.
3. Deserialize that file when you restart the game, to convert the information on the file to your virtual class, again.

If you are not familiar with JSON's, you can check my [JsonManager](https://github.com/EricBatlle/SimpleUnityUtils/tree/master/Assets/Simple_JsonManager) Repo.

Comment: Thanks, used your info and added the coin data through list in json & now its working.

Comment: @AniketUjgare You're welcome! Remember to mark the answer as correct if it is to help others! ^^